Using quick view forms in PCF components
I'm trying to create a PCF component for crm 365 and I'm quite new to it.
Is it possible to show few quick view forms in one PCF? F.e. to show quick view forms for accounts children. I know that I can build custom cards in PCF, but I wonder if I can reuse already existing quick view form for it?
Thank you in advance :)
